# Отправка письма, на подобии как уведомления на ХэшКоде

Tags: email, php, hashcode

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Всех с праздником черт возьми!

[image: Ссылка на картинку]

Собственно, есть обычное письмо, которое высылается на `e-mail` адрес. Прям в почте яндекса, можно нажать в письме на магическую кнопку ''показать цитату''.

Вопрос: может ли кто порадовать, и привести пример `PHP` код такого письма, или хотя бы сказать, как такие письма делаются? Ведь там библиотеку `JQuery` не прикрепишь, и это не совсем `HTML` страница со всеми ее плюсами и минусами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В письмах от ХэшКода используется `blockquote`. Магическая кнопка — это фича Яндекс-почты, у других ничего такого нету.

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо @VladD !

Comment: @mixalef: пожалуйста!